# Set the image fits to aspect ratio

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What I have is

[image]

What I want is to cover the entire blue space behind the image, while keeping its aspect ratio.My code as bellow. Help would much appreciate.

```
            <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
                <Image style={styles.headerImageStyle}
                    source={require('./images/headerimages/headerImage.jpg')} />
            </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#42a1f4',
        height: 125,
    },
    headerImageStyle: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        flex:1,
        height: 125,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        resizeMode: 'contain'
    },
});
```

Comment: I think using `ImageBackground` instead `Image` to render your bg image, then put label in `ImageBackground` tag is better, you can change `resizeMode` to `stretch` to full fill cover view.

Comment: In React Native, there’s no background-image tag; instead, the <Image> component does the heavy lifting.

Comment: I don't know which version you are use but in `react-native 0.52` already has `ImageBackground`. Refer https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting